# How to handle jwt token on client side with middleware in blazor server application

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor, middleware, webapi

I have secured my web API with a Jwt token. I followed several guides on how to set up Authentication on my Web API, and it works perfectly. but what do I do with the token on the client side? I can't find any guides on the second half of adding authentication and authorization to .net core applications.

I have seen one example but in that [example](https://www.prowaretech.com/articles/current/blazor/wasm/jwt-authentication-simple#!), they are directly calling the token from the razor component. In some guides, they are using middlewares like Owin for authentication. I couldn't find anything related to the client side. I don't know whether I should use middleware for calling the client.

What I'm trying to do is:

I trying to do it in a generic way. I can't call the server directly from the razor component. I have lots of web API and everything is protected. I can't directly call the server from each razor page. So I'm trying to do it in a generic way like creating an authclientService and token handler on the client side and trying to inject it in the razor component.

this is what I tried in the client side:

AuthClientService.cs

```
   public class AuthClientService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage;
        private string token;
        private DateTime tokenExpiration;
        private const string TokenKey = "auth_token";
        public AuthClientService(HttpClient httpClient, Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
            this.localStorage = localStorage;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            var token = await localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync(TokenKey);
            // Check if the token is null or expired
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))//|| IsTokenExpired(token))
            {
                // Request a new token
                token = await RequestNewToken();
                // Save the token to local storage
                await localStorage.SetItemAsync(TokenKey, token);
            }
            return token;
        }
        private async Task<string> RequestNewToken()
        {
            var user = new User("hams@email.com", "hams");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth", user);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jwtToken = token.Trim('"');
                // Parse the token and extract the expiration date
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var parsedToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
                tokenExpiration = parsedToken.ValidTo;
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

TokenHandler.cs

```
    public class TokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly AuthClientService authService;
        public TokenHandler(AuthClientService authService)
        {
            this.authService = authService;
        }
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var token = await authService.GetTokenAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
    builder.Services.AddScoped(async sp =>
    {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) };
    // Add the TokenHandler to the HttpClient's pipeline
    var authClientService = sp.GetRequiredService<AuthClientService>();
    var tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(authClientService);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new     System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await authClientService.GetTokenAsync());
    return httpClient;
    });
```

I have tried this but its not working. I don't know how to call the token from the client side in generic way. Please help me out with this.

Thanks!!!